# Como llamar desde una subclase a una clase sin constructor?

Tags: java, poo

Me ecuentro realizando el siguiente ejercicio de programacion;

Clase padre: Employee

```
 public class Employee {
        
        private int empId;
        private String name;
        private double salary;
    
        
        public int getEmpId() {
            return empId;
        }
        
        public void setEmpId(int empId) {
            this.empId = empId;
        }
        
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        public double getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }
        
        public void setSalary(double salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    
    }
```

Subclase: PermanentEmployee

public class PermanentEmployee extends Employee{

```
private double basicPay;
private double hra;
private int experience;


public PermanentEmployee(int empId, String name, double basicPlay, double hrs, int experience) {
    this.experience = experience;
}

public double getBasicPay() {
    return basicPay;
}

public void setBasicPay(double basicPay) {
    this.basicPay = basicPay;
}

public double getHra() {
    return hra;
}

public void setHra(double hra) {
    this.hra = hra;
}

public int getExperience() {
    return experience;
}

public void setExperience(int experience) {
    this.experience = experience;
}

public void calculateSalary() {
    
    double varComponent = 0;
    int empleeExperience= this.getExperience();
    
    if(empleeExperience >= 3) {
        varComponent = 5;
    }
    else if(empleeExperience >= 5) {
        varComponent = 7;
    }
    else if(empleeExperience >= 10) {
        varComponent = 12;
    }
    
   this.setSalary( ((varComponent * this.getBasicPay())/100) + this.basicPay + this.hra);

   System.out.println("Permanent Employee: " + this.getName() + " your salary is " + this.getSalary());
    
}
```

}

la subclase tiene constructor, pero la superclase no tiene no constructor, como es posible que mande a llamar las variables de instancia de la super clase si, no se tiene constructor en la clase padre?

al momento de ejecutarlo el resultado es el siguiente:

**Permanent Employee: null your salary is 0.0**

Se que, se necesita mandar a llamar el constructor de la super clase para que salga el resultado, pero en este caso... como se hace?

Al igual cuando hago el resultado dentro de this.setResult... me sale 0

Comment: Estas confundiendo conceptos.. La clase padre, si tiene un constructor, implicito, que lo que hace es cargar la clase a memoria. Lo que no tiene, es un constructor explicito para darle valores. Eso no implica, que no puedas agregarle valores desde tu constructor, ya que las propiedades estan creadas. No se necesita un constructor.. solo agregar los valores...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicacion! ya entendi1

Answer (score 1):

Estás heredando de la clase `Employee`, por lo que tienes todas las propiedades públicas y protected de la clase padre, pero ¡No las estás seteando! Las recibes por el constructor, pero no haces nada con ellas. Por favor, modifica el constructor de manera que establezcas el valor de tus campos:

```
public PermanentEmployee(int empId, String name, double basicPlay, double hrs, int experience) {
    super();
    this.experience = experience;
    this.setEmpId( empId );
    this.setName( name );
    this.setBasicPay( basicPlay );
    this.setHra( hrs );
}
```

Recuerda siempre que, si no se declara de manera explícita un constructor, el compilador crea uno por defecto que no recibe parámetros.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! me salio perfectamente bien, solamente me podrias exmplicar el this.setEmpId(empId) porfavor!!

Comment: A ver. Usualmente en tu constructor seteas los campos de tu clase, por ejemplo, tu mismo agregaste la línea `this.experience = experience;` para setear la experiencia. Cuando heredas, la clase hija, también tiene que setear las propiedades de la clase padre. Ahora bien, si hubieras declarado las propiedades `protected` hubieras podido hacer `this.empId = empId;` pero como las declarastes privadas, para poder acceder a la clase padre y setear los valores solo te quedan los `setters` y `getters`, por eso hay que usar  `this.setEmpId(empId)`.

Comment: La línea  `this.setEmpId(empId)` dice literalmente : _"Voy a establecer en este objeto que estoy creando la propiedad `empId` al valor  `empId` que me pasan por parámetro."_.

Comment: muchas gracias!! me queda claro que debo de estudiar mucho para ser un crack como tu, te agradezco el tiempo por ayudarme :)